# Output in a Table python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want my program to output rows*columns in that many rows and columns. For instance, table(2,3) would output

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

So far I have

```
    def table(rows, columns):
         print(*range(1,rows*columns+1))
```

It prints rows*columns, but I don't know how to print it in a tabular format. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a for loop before your print statement like this:

```
    def table(rows, columns):
        for i in range(rows):
            print(*range(1+i*columns, 1+(i+1)*columns))
```

This way you print a new line for each iteration of the loop and the range increases by the number of columns.

Comment: Not bad, but you can eliminate the multiplications by giving the `i` range a `step` arg of `columns`. That will make the inner loop easier to read, and more efficient (not that efficiency is an issue here).